# Why is the max. number of intersections of k lines in $\mathbb{R}^2$ = $\binom{k}{2}$?

Tags: combinatorics, geometry

Why is the maximum number of intersections of k lines in $\mathbb{R}^2$ = $\binom{k}{2}$?

Comment: Suppose every pair of lines intersects.  How many times can two lines intersect?  How many intersections could there be in all?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Consider two lines : the max number of intersections is 1.
Then the third line will intersect at max the two others lines so the max number of intersection is 1+2=3.
Then the fourth line will intersect at max the three others lines so the max number of intersection is 1+2+3=6.

By induction, it is therefore easy to show that the maximum number of intersections is $$\sum_{i=1}^{k-1} i = \frac{(k-1)k}{2} = \binom{k}{2}$$

Answer (score 5):

Each pair of line can intersect each other once (as far as they aren't the same line) and there is $\binom{k}{2}$ pairs among k lines.